# Make text in span fade in on parent hover

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, fadein

In this piece of code

```html
<div class="uploader">
  <a class="btn">
    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
    <span>SEND</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

how to make SEND fade in while div is hovered using CSS only?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```css
.uploader {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.btn {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}

.uploader:hover > .btn {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="uploader">
  <a class="btn">
    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
    <span>SEND</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

use `opacity` to specify the visibility of the element and `transition` to make the delay

```css
.uploader a span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}
.uploader:hover a span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="uploader">
  Hover this >>>
  <a class="btn">
    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
    <span>SEND</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

or even simpler

```
<div class="uploader">
  <a class="btn">
    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
    <span class="hide">SEND</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

.

```
.hide{
    opacity:0; 
  transition:opacity 1s linear;
}
.uploader:hover .hide{  
  opacity:1; 
}
```